# If a few of my eggs crack when making them hard-boiled, is it still safe to eat them?

Tags: eggs, hard-boiled-eggs

I was making about a dozen hard boiled eggs last night and a few of them cracked when boiling.  The yolk partially came out of the shell but I continued to cook them as other ones in the pot were fine.   Is it safe to consume the partially broken eggs after they cool?

Comment: are you sure it was the yolk (yellow?) If some of the white comes out it's no big deal but I usually trim the part away that came out because it is rubbery. Use the cracked ones first.

Comment: very little yolk but a lot of white (between all 12 eggs)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it certainly is safe to eat them, it happens all the time. They won't last quite as long in the fridge as ones which don't crack, but as long as you eat them in a couple of days you are fine. They may look like nuclear mutants but they will taste the same.

To avoid cracked eggs heat the water more gently so they come to a boil slower, heating too quickly can cause the eggs to crack.

Comment: Heated water makes for better boiling? I feel there's something missing here

Comment: Heating the eggs too quickly can make eggs crack, heating the water more gently, i.e. slower helps to avoid that @npst.

Comment: Ah, "gently". I see.

Comment: I've edited to rephrase, hope that is clearer.

Comment: Maybe it was my fault for being someone who brings water to a boil before adding the eggs (for timing reasons). Now I understand your (valid) point

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They may taste watery but they won't hurt.